# Modulo with fractions.Fraction class

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, modulo, fractions

My aim is to find `np.mod(np.array[int], some_number)` for a numpy array containing very large integers. Some_number is rational, but in general not an exact decimal fraction. I want to make sure that the modulos are as accurate as possible since I need to bin the results for a histogram in a later step, so any errors due to floating-point precision might mean that values will end up in the wrong bin.

I am aware that the modulo function with floats is limited by floating-point precision, so I am hesitating to use `np.mod(array[int], float)`.
I then came across the fractions module of the python library. Can someone give advice as to whether the results obtained via `np.mod(np.array[int], Fraction(int1, int2))` would be more accurate than using a float? If not, what is the best approach for such a problem?

Comment: Your numpy array contains integers?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the sort of values involved? "very large integers" is a bit puzzling here, since NumPy typically doesn't offer dtypes larger than `np.uint64`. Do you have an array of dtype `dtype('O')`?

Comment: The numpy array contains np.int64 integers (usually around a million of them) and some_number is somewhere between 10 to 100, so about 17 orders of magnitude smaller than the elements of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a fraction `some_number=n/d`

Computing the modulo is like performing this division:

```
a = q*(n/d) + (r/d)
```

the remainder is a fraction with numerator `r`.
It can be written like this:

```
a*d = q * n + r
```

The problem you have is that `a*d` could overflow.
But the problem can be written like this:

```
a = q1 * n + r1
d = q2 * n + r2

a*d = (q1*q2*n+q1*r2+q2*r1) * n + (r1*r2)
```

given that n/d is between 10 and 100, n>d, q2=0, r2=d, the algorithm is

1. compute a modulo n => r1
2. compute (r1*d) modulo n => r
3. divide r by d => a modulo n/d

If it's for putting in bins, you don't need step 3.

Comment: Could you comment a bit more on how you get from the equation for a*d to the two separate equations for a and d?

Comment: 1) we decompose each term of the product `a*d` with an Euclidean division, 2) we multiply the decompositions `(q1 * n + r1)*(q2 * n + r2)` 3) we see that this product can be written `someting*n + (r1*r2)` 4) `r1<n` and `r2 < n` but `r1*r2` could be >= n, so we perform another division to obtain `a*d` modulo n: `(r1*r2)%n`

Comment: This page has implementation of python/c, etc. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expressing-a-fraction-as-a-natural-number-under-modulo-m/